# Why do we need multiple background-color rules?

Tags: css, less

I'm a novice in Css and it's difficult to search for this specific case on the internet, so I post a question here.

I'm working on an existing code base and I see something like this.

```
li {
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I don't understand the meaning of `\9`. But it looks to me the rules are duplicates and I should remove one of them.

Could you please explain the `\9` and should I remove one rule? Thanks.

The reason I'm asking because I'm converting some css files to less files and `\9` is causing a compilation problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500732/what-does-mean-in-a-css-hex-color-notation could be duplicate

Comment: @Ashish Balchandani: could I remove one of them? and which one should I remove? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\9` is an old Internet Explorer hack, which makes it work in IE only (8 and lower)
rgba is the way to go you can safely delete the `\9` rule

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS hack for IE 7, 8, & 9.

To find out more, please check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property) link.

Answer (score 2):

This is an IE hack.  For more details see http://webdood.com/?p=57.